# PHP Quickbooks API issue with allow_fopen_url

Tags: php, oauth, quickbooks-online

I am using Quickbooks PHP API and it is working fine when we set allow_url_fopen to true.

> But when we set allow_url_fopen to false then this API is not
> working.
>
> I found that fetch function of OAuth library is not getting any
> response.
>
> When I debug, it gives error like this "Fatal error:  Uncaught
> exception 'OAuthException' with message 'making the request failed
> (dunno why)' "

For use OAuth, we have to set allow_url_fopen to true?

Answer (score 0):

allow_url_fopen allows functions such as fopen, fsockopen to be URL aware, as a result, these functions can read remote data. If you turn this setting off, these functions are no longer URL aware, which means you cannot use URL to open a file. I suspect the API is using these function(s) to allow for remote connections. This setting is a security feature, which stops your scripts from accessing remote files.

Comment: API is using OAuth library and for get content, it is using its fetch (http://php.net/manual/en/oauth.fetch.php) function.

Comment: The fetch method is most likely using one of the functions I mentioned earlier. As you are using oAuth library, it is possible to compile it, with libcurl, as I understand it, lib curl does not take allow_url_fopen setting into consideration.